# When does the conditional expectation of the sum of random variables match with the sum their respective conditional expectations?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, conditional-expectation, random-walk, expected-value

I am studying stochastic processes. While studying random walk I acquainted with a notation $N_i$ where $$N_i = \mathrm {Total\ number\ of\ times\ of\ visit\ to\ i}.$$ Let $(X_n)_{n \geq 0}$ be a Markov chain and $S$ be the state space. Then clearly $N_i = \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \mathbb{1}_{[X_n=i]}$, for some $i \in S$. Now suppose I want to calculate the conditional expectation of $N_j$ given $X_0=i$, for some $i,j \in S$. Let me denote it by $E_i[N_j]$. Then $E_i[N_j]=E[\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \mathbb{1}_{[X_n=j]}|X_0=i]$. My instructor said that $E[\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \mathbb{1}_{[X_n=j]}|X_0=i] = \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} E[\mathbb{1}_{[X_n=j]}|X_0=i]=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} P[X_n=j|X_0=i] =\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} {p_{ij}}^{(n)}$.

Now my question is "Why does the last equality hold"? What would be the reason behind it?  Please help me in this regard.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The equalty follows from Fubini's theorem. It is true since the terms of the sum are nonnegative.

**More details** 
The statement of Fubini's theorem can be found here
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem

Now let $\mu$ be the conditional probability measure on $\Omega$,
$$
\mu(A) = P(A|X_0 = i),\qquad \forall A.
$$
Let $\nu$ be the counting measure on $\mathbb R_+$,
$$
\nu(B) = \text{Card}(B\cap \mathbb N).
$$
Let $f(a,\omega) = 1_{[X_{[a]}(\omega)=j]}$ for every $(a,\omega)\in \mathbb R_+\times\Omega$. Then, we have
\begin{align}
E\bigg[\sum_{n} 1_{[X_{n}(\omega)=j]} \Big| X_0 = i\bigg] & = \int_{\Omega}\bigg[\int_{R_+} f(a,\omega) \nu({\rm d}a)\bigg]\,\mu(d\omega)\\
&= \int_{R_+}\bigg[\int_{\Omega} f(a,\omega)\mu(d\omega) \bigg]\,\nu({\rm d}a)\\
&=\sum_{n} E\bigg[ 1_{[X_{n}(\omega)=j]} \Big| X_0 = i\bigg].
\end{align}

Comment: What is Fubini's theorem @Arnak?

Comment: Would you please deduce RHS from LHS in your answer? Then it will help me a lot. Thank you very much.

Comment: The Fubini theorem tells that you can permute two integrals, sums or an integral and a sum if the summands or integrands satisfy some assumptions. The most popular assumptions are absolute integrability or positiveness. If one of these is true, you can permute a sum and an  integral. The conditional expectation being the integral wrt the conditional probability measure, you can apply Fubini's theorem.

Answer (score -2):

It holds because of the [linearity of conditional expectations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation#Basic_properties) and the [monotone convergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem#Beppo_Levi's_monotone_convergence_theorem_for_Lebesgue_integral).

The linearity of conditional expectations means that

$$ \mathbb E[X + Y \vert E] = \mathbb E[X\vert E] + \mathbb E[Y \vert E]. $$

Here, $E$ is some event (or even, more generally, a $\sigma$-algebra). This linearity always holds.

We need to appeal to monotone convergence because of the infinite sum. In particular, we have that

\begin{align*}
\mathbb E_i[N_j] &= \mathbb E_i \left[\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mathbb 1_{[X_n = j]}\right] \\
& = \mathbb E_i \left[\lim_{m \to \infty} \sum_{n=1}^m \mathbb 1_{[X_n = j]}\right] \\
&= \lim_{m \to \infty}\mathbb E_i \left[\sum_{n=1}^m \mathbb 1_{[X_n = j]}\right] \\
&= \lim_{m \to \infty}\sum_{n=1}^m\mathbb E_i \left[ \mathbb 1_{[X_n = j]}\right] \\
&= \sum_{n=1}^\infty\mathbb E_i \left[ \mathbb 1_{[X_n = j]}\right].
\end{align*}

The third equality is where I appealed to monotone convergence, and the fourth is where I used linearity. The rest are definitions.

An example where we cannot appeal directly to the linearity of conditional expectations is when *the number of terms being summed over is random*. For example, consider a compound Poisson process $$Y_t = \sum_{i=1}^{N_t} X_i,$$

where $N_t$ is a Poisson process, and the $X_i$'s are iid and independent of $N$. Here, we have that

$$ \mathbb E [Y_t] \neq \sum_{i=1}^{N_t} \mathbb E[X_i], $$

precisely because the number of terms you are summing over is random. The same expression above holds for conditional expectation.

Comment: Why does limit and conditional expectation commute?

Comment: @Dbchatto67 I explain this in my answer. This is because of the monotone convergence theorem.

Comment: What is $f_k$ here? Is $f_k=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{k} \Bbb{1}_{[X_n=i]}$?

Comment: Then $\{f_k \}$ is a non-decreasing sequence of non-negative measurable functions. But then what do I do?

Comment: In fact $f_k$'s are simple functions.

Comment: The Lebesgue integral of $f_k$ becomes $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{k} P[X_n=i]$. Right?

Comment: Please explain clearly what you have written on your answer.